adding todo: SendTransactionError: Simulation failed
adding todo: SendTransactionError: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0xbc4. 
Logs: 
[
  "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
  "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
  "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program TLgsKcCjHfyEbL2k6giZDCauDskQmEUzrKKzSw12wKH invoke [1]",
  "Program log: Instruction: AddTodo",
  "Program log: AnchorError caused by account: user_profile. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized.",
  "Program TLgsKcCjHfyEbL2k6giZDCauDskQmEUzrKKzSw12wKH consumed 3921 of 199700 compute units",
  "Program TLgsKcCjHfyEbL2k6giZDCauDskQmEUzrKKzSw12wKH failed: custom program error: 0xbc4"
]. 
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (index.browser.esm.js:7525:13)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (index.browser.esm.js:7490:20)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (index.js:1122:23)
    at async AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (index.js:1012:20)
    at async addTodo (todo.js:152:31)
    at async handleSubmit (index.js:37:13)

const addTodo = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (program && publicKey) {
            try {
                setTransactionPending(true);
    
                // Ensure userProfile is initialized (implement your own initialization logic here)
                const profilePda = await initializeUser();
                if (!profilePda) {
                    console.error('Failed to initialize userProfile');
                    return;
                }
    
                const content = input.trim();
                if (!content) {
                    setTransactionPending(false);
                    return;
                }
    
                const [todoPda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
                    [Buffer.from('TODO_STATE'), publicKey.toBuffer(), Uint8Array.from([lastTodo])],
                    program.programId
                );
    
                // Create a transaction without manually setting blockhash and fee payer
                const tx = new anchor.web3.Transaction().add(
                    await program.methods.addTodo(content).accounts({
                        todoAccount: todoPda,
                        userProfile: profilePda,
                        authority: publicKey,
                        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
                    }).instruction()
                );
    
                // Solana's provider will handle fetching the latest blockhash and fee payer
                const txSig = await program.provider.sendAndConfirm(tx);
                console.log('Transaction successful with signature:', txSig);
    
                // Fetch updated todos after adding a new todo
                const todoAccounts = await program.account.todoAccount.all([authorFilter(publicKey.toString())]);
                setTodos(todoAccounts);  // Update todos state with the latest todos
    
                setLastTodo((prev) => prev + 1);
                setInput(""); // Clear the input field after adding todo
                toast.success('Successfully added todo.');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error adding todo:', error);
                toast.error(error.toString());
            } finally {
                setTransactionPending(false);
            }
        }
    };
    ```


0xbc4 is hex and 3012 in base 10 which is the code for passing in an Account that is not yet initialized and anchor will throw an error if it isn't
ref: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/594b449f4d2fdff6da9641ad3d0f27d544cc3b89/ts/packages/anchor-errors/src/index.ts#L153
You may have forgotten to initialize user_profile in your instructions or a previous one.
Use the init macro in your instruction or initialize it before calling the addTodo ix.
